# chrome.tabs.highlight giving error "No tab at index"

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

When calling `chrome.tabs.highlight({'tabs': tabId}, function(){});` I'm getting this error:

`Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.highlight: No tab at index: 7355.`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

chrome.tabs.highlight requires a tab index, not a tabId. You can convert a tabId into an index using chrome.tabs.get:

```
chrome.tabs.get(tabId, function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.highlight({'tabs': tab.index}, function() {});
});
```

Comment: Note that the callback in chrome.tabs.highlight should be optional, but due to a Chrome bug it is currently required: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=417564

Comment: I just hope those are the last mandatory-useless-callback cases to squash. I remember similar problems in `notifications` API.

Answer (score 4):

Another important thing (in addition of using the tab index) is to provide the `windowId`. This is not documented in the official chrome docs, but helps if a different window or inspector is active.

```
chrome.tabs.highlight({
  windowId: tab.windowId,
  tabs: tab.index
}, function () {});
```

Answer (score 1):

This function does not take tab IDs, but instead the tab indices (positions within the window)